# If I restart xinetd service , does it impact the currently active FTP connections?

Tags: linux, ftp, services, xinetd

In my Linux system FTP server is running from xinetd . I want to make a configuration change inside the **/etc/xinetd.d/** directory for the FTP server launch with respect to the arguments passed to the FTP server .

So for this change do I have to restart the xinetd service ?

Also if I restart the xinetd service ,does it make any issues to the currently active FTP connections to the server ?

Comment: No, restarting `xinetd` doesn't impact any current sessions. It forks a new process for each connection, and they continue independently of the original `xinetd` process.